# Android: How to get all data which a list item hold?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a very complicated list item as shown in picture. 
[image: very complicated list item]

it has a title , image , rating (rating bar) , rating count (Text View), favorite indicator (image), favorite count (Text View), like indicator , like count (Text View), tried indicator (image) and tried count (Text View).

it gets all these data from sqlite db via this custom cursor adapter :

```
 public class RecListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public RecListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView thumbImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    ImageView favImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageFav);
    ImageView likeImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageLike);
    ImageView triedImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageTried);

    thumbImg.setImageResource(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_THUMB_ID)));

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_FAV)) == 1) {
        favImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_on);
    }

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_LIKED)) == 1) {
        likeImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumb_on);
    }

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_TRIED)) == 1) {
        triedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.tried_on);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    TextView favCnt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtFavCnt);
    TextView likeCnt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLikeCnt);
    TextView triedCnt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTriedCnt);

    title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_NAME)));
    favCnt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_FAV_CNT)));
    likeCnt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_LIKE_CNT)));
    triedCnt.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_TRIED_CNT)));

    RatingBar rating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.list_ratingbar);
    rating.setRating(cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_RATING)));
}
}
```

right now I'm sending row id to a detail activity which query the db to get the same data again which mean that I query the db twice for the same data

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(RecipeDetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, String.valueOf(id));
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

what I want to do is send that data from list item to details activity to display to save the second query

I thought that I can get reference to those views and get values from them but this will be very complex process because of image views , text views and rating bar.

Sure there is an easier and smarter way to do this but I can't figure it out.

I did a lot of search with no luck.

Can you guide me what can I do here?

Comment: well the smart way is to split the Sqllite code into one class to perform different functions so you can access them from any activity without repeating code  -- http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Make a ArrayList<Model> from your cursor, where a Model instance stores data in a single row of SQLite and use that ArrayList in your adapter?

Comment: @Tasos I'm doing this already, it's not the code that I don't want to repeat,  it's doing query to data base again to get the same data.

Comment: You can make this Model parcelable and send it to the next activity directly, which is obviously better than calling putExtra for every data you want to send

Comment: @Sourabh I didn't get it clearly, can you give a code snippet to clarify thing little bit?

Comment: well you have no option then, either pull the data from the views or the db.  any other way such as arrays etc will duplicate data and possibly make it harder to update the ratings etc in the database as you will have to it 2ice in array and in the db

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

*Not Tested!*

add a method in your adapter, something like this

```
public void getData(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    int p = cursor.getPosition;
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    // ... get data here
    cursor.moveToPosition(p);
}
```

change the return type to whatever you prefer

### Option 2

Make an ArrayList<Model> from your cursor, where Model could be something like

```
class Model {
    public String title;
    public String image;
    public boolean rated;
    public int ratingCount;
    public boolean favorited;
    public int favoriteCount;
    public boolean liked;
    public int likeCount;
    public boolean tried;
    public int triedCount;
}
```

and use [ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, java.util.List)) with your ListView

Comment: Thank you I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: @Mohammad -- i wouldn't go for the array option. whats the point. assuming you can update ratings, etc in the details page you will have to save the changes in the array and in the database so how is this smarter. you will end up with more code

Comment: @Tasos It's not the code that I want to shrink, I want to decrease the number db queries my friend because it takes much time.And your point of view is good too.

Comment: But he'd have to update the data from cursor anyway if the detail activity makes any changes. Plus to get data at any location, he'd have to move the cursor to that location anyway. I'd choose using an array over cursor anytime, cursors are much slower

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the data to be duplicated in memory? once for the cursor and once again for the array?

Comment: @Sourabh In option 1 how can I get position of that row in the cursor? Is it the same position that I get in the `OnItemClickListener`  method?

Comment: @Mohammad -- its takes a lot of time. if it takes a lot of time then the list view also takes a lot of time to populate so your app is slow anyway. i assume you have 1000's of records in the db. wouldn't it be better to have the db on a server and go with Option 2 pulling data from the server using json which is 100 times faster. or do you have that sqlite db in the app for favorites and bookmarks?

Comment: @Tasos yes I have this db in the app for favorites and bookmarks and it takes a lot of time because it presents data with images, querying the db + populating list item with images increases processing time I think. I'm not an expert in android so I'm trying to enhance my experience.

Comment: @Tasos is pulling data from a remote server will be faster than querying a local db? I thought it will be 100 times slower :)

Comment: @Mohammad -- ahh now it makes sense. well you want to speed things up then use a URL for the images and get them from the Net instead of storing them in the DB. they will be cached anyway so the request to URL will only be done once, the rest of the time it will be from the cache so no nore Net Rquests. use something like picasso -- http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @Mohammad -- outsource its 100 times faster especially when you have a million + records to go through -- try this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: @Tasos No I'm not storing Images in the db, just the cursor adapter expresses data with image like this: 
       `ImageView likeImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageLike);`
      
`if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.REC_LIKED)) == 1) {`
        `likeImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumb_on);
    }`

Comment: @Tasos yes thank you I'll give it a try. And thank you very much for your concern ;)

Comment: @Sourabh I can't get option 1 to work. How would I make a reference to the cursor adapter in details activity with the same cursor that the list uses?

Comment: You can't and shouldn't pass cursor objects to other activities. Ideally you should close the cursor in onPause/onStop as open cursors can cause a crash. So you'd have to pass data to detail activity which will create a new cursor. It shouldn't be a big deal if you use `WHERE` clause, it'll be just one row anyway. And yes `position` in `getData(int position)` is same as in `OnItemClickListener`.